# Nondiagonal $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Can someone give an example of a nondiagonal, $3 \times 3$ matrix
that is diagonalizable but is not invertible?

Explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you need your matrix to have an eigenvalue of $0$.

Comment: Any nondiagonal matrix with 3 distinct eigenvalues, one of them $0$, will do.  Take any nondiagonal 2-by-2 matrix $A$ with 2 distinct nonzero eigenvalues.  Then let $B$ have $A$ in the upper left block and zeros everywhere else.  $B$ has a zero column so it is not invertible, and the eigenvalues of $A$ are also eigenvalues of $B$

Answer (score 3):

Start off by getting a diagonal matrix $A$ with a $0$ on the diagonal so it isn't invertible.

> For instance consider $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &0\\ 0 &1 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$.

Now you want a non diagonal matrix. Just consider $B^{-1}AB$ for some appropiate $B$. Some $B$ not too simple.

> A possibility is $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &3\\ 0 &4 &5\\ 0 & 0 & 6  \end{bmatrix}$. It clearly is invertible and $A\sim B^{-1}AB=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 &-3\\ 0 &1 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore a possible answer is $B^{-1}AB$.

Now find your own $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3):

$A = \begin{bmatrix}−3&−2&0\\2&−2&0\\13&-4&0\end{bmatrix}$

For the structure of the matrix, you easily can derive an approach for any dimension.

See it?